# Using ARtoolkit with unity and ZED camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I'm trying to use the ARToolkit with unity, using ZED as a stereo camera.
My problem is that the toolkit recognizes the camera automatically as non-stereo  camera, where the frame displayed is composed of the two frames from both cameras (left and right).

Anyone had the same problem.
Any solutions?

I'm using windows, unity 2017 and ARToolKit package for unity.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ZED camera outputs a single frame composed of both images side-by-side, and this is not natively supported by ARToolKit for multi-camera (stereo) input. Current versions of ARToolKit expect two distinct video streams.

Which OS are you using? It shouldn't be hard to add support for side-by-side stereo input to ARToolKit.

Comment: Thnks. I'm using windows OS, unity 2017 and ARToolKit for unity.